# How do I add text to my draw.io doc?

Tags: app.diagrams.net, text

I don't know how to add text. Please help, I know there is a button that says "text" on it yet there is know way too *add* a text bubble.

Answer (score 5):

You can type text into every single shape. Just select one on your diagram and start typing.

[image]

Also, you can double click anywhere in space on a diagram to add text there. Just select the text option, usually the first option is the popup that appears.

[image]

Comment: how can a shape be "captioned"? I mean, text in the shapes I'm using look terrible.

Comment: @tedder42 Please ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have two ways to add plain text:

- Double click on the canvas (or hit <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+X</kbd>) to insert a non-linkable text block, and start typing
- Insert the *text* symbol (from *General* menu), and start typing

Any element can also have text, or be replaced into a pure text element by <kbd>Alt-dragging</kbd> the *text* element onto the other element.

Do note that the first version here is not possible to connect to other nodes, whilst the other is an ordinary node with ordinary connectivity.